# HBitmap byte array to php

Tags: php, c++, winapi, base64

i'm trying to make screenshot in my console win32 application in this way:

```
char* getScreenshot(){
    HDC hScreenDC = CreateDC("DISPLAY", NULL, NULL, NULL);
    HDC hMemoryDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hScreenDC);

    int x = GetDeviceCaps(hScreenDC, HORZRES);
    int y = GetDeviceCaps(hScreenDC, VERTRES);

    HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hScreenDC, x, y);
    size_t width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN);
    size_t height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN);
    HBITMAP hOldBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hBitmap);

    BitBlt(hMemoryDC, 0, 0, width, height, hScreenDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    hBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hOldBitmap);
    char* buffer = new char[x*y]();
    GetBitmapBits(hBitmap,x*y,buffer);
    DeleteDC(hMemoryDC);
    DeleteDC(hScreenDC);
    return buffer;
}
```

buffer should be the byte array containing the hbitmap screenshot.

Then i send it throught a socket in this way:

```
char *buff = getScreenshot();
string a(buff);
send(hClientSocket, buff, a.length(), 0);
if (hClientSocket!=INVALID_SOCKET)
    closesocket(hClientSocket);
```

And i catch if from php in this way:

```
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
set_time_limit(15);
$succ = socket_connect($sock, $ip, $port) or die("timeout");
$output = "";
while($resp = socket_read($sock, 1000)) {
   $output .= $resp;
}
socket_close($sock);
$base64 = base64_encode($output);
echo "<img src='data:image/bmp;base64,$base64' />";
```

My problem is that i can't to show image using the method written upon.

What could be the problem?
Where i'm wrong?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Based on what @Peter R. Bloomfield says, i changed my function to:

```
char* getScreenshot(int* length){
   ...
   *length = x*y;
   ...
}
```

and send to socket:

```
int length;
char *buff = getScreenshot(&length);
send(hClientSocket, buff, length, 0);
```

but it continue to avoid to show...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A BMP image is not just the "bits" in the image (which is what is in your `buffer`). A BMP image has a header with things like the width, height, bits per pixel and a few other such items.

The simplest approach would be to save your HBITMAP as an image file, and then load the filedata in your socket code. If you don't want to save it as a file, then you will have to construct a compatible header and send that before the actual image data.

At the very least to confirm your principles, try the "save bitmap to file" approach before working out the code to make a header.

Answer (score 1):

This is bound to cause problems:

```
char *buff = getScreenshot();
string a(buff);
```

You're taking an array of arbitrary binary data, and trying to convert it to a `string` object. The `char *` constructor will be expecting a null-terminated string. That means it will stop the first time one of the pixels in your image has a value of 0 in any RGB component.

For transmitting raw pixel data, you'd be better off avoiding the conversion to the `string` object altogether. Just pass the `char *` pointer straight to the `send()` function. You would obviously need to tell it the correct size though (anything like `strlen()` will have the same problems as the `string` constructor). You could pass the size information out of your `getScreenshot()` function via reference parameter perhaps.

I suspect you'll also have a problem of missing header information when you output the image in HTML. The client browser currently has no way to tell what the dimensions of the image are supposed to be (i.e. how many pixels wide/high), or what the data format is.

Comment: thank you for response. i try to do what you say but it continue give me same results